# Regex to pick out correct time in powershell depending on what is next to it

Tags: regex, datetime, powershell, time, scripting

I am using powershell with regex to try and extract the following time from the line below "01:42:35". However I want to ignore the time "02:42:35" but I am unsure of how to do it.

2013-07-04 02:42:35 Alert   172.172.19.9    Jul  4 01:42:35 ...

Currently I am using this time regex: `$time_regex = "(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)"`
How can I adapt this to the above specification?

Note: the time i am trying to get is not at the end of the line and the second time always has a date next to it in the format "Jul 4 " whereas the first time has a date next to it in the format "2013-07-04"

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is your criterion for matching the second but not the first time?

Comment: The second time always has a date next to it in the format "Jul 4 " whereas the first time has a date next to it in the format "2013-07-04"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$time_regex = "(?<=\w+ \d+ )(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)"
```

will only match a time string that's preceded by an alphanumeric "word" and a number.

Comment: Sorry is should have been clear- that is only part of the line so it wont be at the end of the line.

Comment: Then what is the difference between the two time strings that the regex needs to look at?

Comment: The second time always has a date next to it in the format "Jul 4 " whereas the first time has a date next to it in the format "2013-07-04"

Answer (score 1):

If is always at the end of the line use:

```
$t = "2013-07-04 02:42:35 Alert 172.172.19.9 Jul 4 01:42:35"
 [regex]::match( $t, "(\d+:){2}(\d+)$" )  | select -expa value
```

Edit after comment:

try this:

```
$time_regex  = "(?<= \d+ )(\d+:){2}\d+"
```

Comment: Sorry is should have been clear- that is only part of the line so it wont be at the end of the line.